# Git: Merging file using diff merge tool the base file is blank

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I am trying to resolve conflicts, using diff merge tool In sourcetree by right click on the file name, I opened external merge tool.

Diff merge tool is opened, in the left side it shows the local file changes and in the right side it shows the remote file changes, **but in the middle the base file is blank.**
Could anyone help me on these issue..

Comment: Do you have changes in the file or is it a new file that was added in local and remote?

Comment: Its not a new file, we have some changes in the file.

Comment: What merge tool does SourceTree open by default? Is there a built in one?

Comment: SourceTree does not have a built-in merge tool, so it uses an external one. You can allow to start the Araxis merge tool, select from a list of supported tools from the options in sourcetree.